# Unable to Access process.env Variables When Running "Current File" in IntelliJ for Model Files

Tags: node.js, npm, intellij-idea, environment

I am encountering an issue with accessing process.env variables in my Node.js application's model files when running "current file" in IntelliJ. Strangely, I am able to access these variables without any issues when running "current file" on app.js.

I have tried setting the environment variables in my system's environment variables as well as in a .env file in the root directory of my project. I have also checked that the variables are being set correctly by logging them to the console in app.js.

I am using Node.js version 16 and the dotenv package to load my environment variables. I have also tried using cross-env to set the variables in my package.json file, but the issue still persists.

I suspect that the issue may be related to how process.env variables are being loaded or initialized in my application. However, I am not sure where to begin troubleshooting.

Can anyone please suggest a solution or provide guidance on how to resolve this issue when running "current file" in IntelliJ for my model files? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What OS do you use? Did you logout/login or reboot after changing the system environment variables?

Comment: I'm using windows 11. I have tried rebooting

Comment: Please provide the code that is reading the env variable, the screenshot of the run configuration and the screenshot of the system env variables dialog showing this variable is set.

Comment: Code that reads env variable https://pastebin.com/XR1jWqZ5. The imgur image shows the example env file, I have another legit env file, with redacted info, but the same template https://imgur.com/a/rlACBv3

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear how you run this project so that it reads the env file. Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub.

Comment: https://github.com/kristofferous/stackof.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your [sample project](https://github.com/kristofferous/stackof.git), right-click in the file, [Modify Run Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9709A.png).

Set Working directory to the root project directory (where `.env` file is located).

Set JavaScript file to the location of the file you want to run relative to the working directory.

[image: run config]

Now it works:

[image: works]

Comment: What if I want to do the same with the "Current file" configuration? It worked a few days ago

Comment: In this case, you will need to have your .js files and .env files in the same directory and edit the default run configuration to use this directory as the working directory, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html#change-template.